# Three.js Collada example: "empty or non-existing file"

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I`m trying to get the Three.js Collada loader example to work. I run a local http server so I am able to load images for textures and models, and I have been able to run every other sample, including the .obj loader and blender scene.
The problem is that when I run the collada loader example, I get an error: "ColladaLoader: Empty or non-existing file (./models/collada/pump/pump.dae)"

Has anyone else seen this? Is there a workaround? thanks!

Edit: I have checked if the files exist, I have tried moving them to all possible locations.

Comment: this may very well be an extremely stupid question but...have you checked to see if the file exists and has content?

Comment: Check the network panel on the developer tools and see if it's trying to load it and where it's trying to load it. I recall having some issues on paths on an old version of the library.

Comment: Looking at the network panel, the "/models/collada/monster" file used in the example is indeed loaded @ ColladaLoader.js:104 with status code 200 "OK". The error is thrown when request.responseXML is null @ ColladaLoader.js:72

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appears that you are using an old version of the three.js library. Try updating to the current version r.52.

Here is the pull request where this issue was resolved: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/2451